# Converting a pandas MultiIndex DataFrame from rows-wise to column-wise

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index, zipline

I'm working in zipline and pandas and have converted a `pandas.Panel` to a `pandas.DataFrame` using the `to_frame()` method. This is the resulting `pandas.DataFrame` which as you can see is multi-indexed:

```
                                  price
major                     minor                
2008-01-03 00:00:00+00:00 SPY    129.93
                          KO      26.38
                          PEP     64.78
2008-01-04 00:00:00+00:00 SPY    126.74
                          KO      26.43
                          PEP     64.59
2008-01-07 00:00:00+00:00 SPY    126.63
                          KO      27.05
                          PEP     66.10
2008-01-08 00:00:00+00:00 SPY    124.59
                          KO      27.16
                          PEP     66.63
```

I need to convert this frame to look like this:

```
                          SPY     KO     PEP
2008-01-03 00:00:00+00:00 129.93  26.38  64.78
2008-01-04 00:00:00+00:00 126.74  26.43  64.59
2008-01-07 00:00:00+00:00 126.63  27.05  66.10
2008-01-08 00:00:00+00:00 124.59  27.16  66.63
```

I've tried the pivot method, stack/unstack, etc. but these methods are not what I'm looking for. I'm really quite stuck at this point and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Because you have a MultiIndex in place already, `stack` and `unstack` are what you want to use to move rows to cols and vice versa.  That being said, `unstack` should do exactly what you want to accomplish.  If you have a DataFrame `df` then `df2 = df.unstack('minor')` should do the trick.  Or more simply, since by default `stack`/`unstack` use the innermost level, `df2 = df.unstack()`.

Comment: Aargh; beat me to it.  `pivot` should work too, after resetting the index, i.e. `df.reset_index().pivot("major", "minor")` (with or without a `, "price")` or `["price"]`, depending on how important whether the name is still floating around is.)

Comment: Ha nice, I was obviously not using unstack correctly, thanks.